# AWheeledVehicle movement in c++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

using Unreal Engine 4, I am attempting to move my vehicle (AWheeledVehicle) in the forward direction. I am correctly referencing the correct vehicle, but still it won't move. 
Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Attached below is my Vehicle and Controller class

AAIWheeledVehicle

```
AAIWheeledVehicle::AAIWheeledVehicle(){
    AIControllerClass = AMyAIVehicleController::StaticClass();
}
```

AMyAIVehicleController

```
void AMyAIVehicleController::Possess(APawn *pawn){
    Super::Possess(pawn);
    //FVector location2 = pawn->GetActorLocation(); // -11310, 8910, 0

    // initialize location of target point
    location.X = -9620.0f;
    location.Y = 8910.0f;
    location.Z = 0.0f;

    scaleValue = 1.0f;

    target = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<ATargetPoint>(location, FRotator::ZeroRotator);
    target->SetActorLocation(location);

    // get AI vehicle reference
    vehicle = Cast<AWheeledVehicle>(pawn);
    // add forward movement to vehicle, scale = 1
    vehicle->AddMovementInput(GetActorForwardVector(), scaleValue);

    //vehicle->GetVehicleMovement()->Velocity.X = 1.0f;
    //vehicle->GetVehicleMovement()->SetThrottleInput(1.0f);
    //vehicle->GetVehicleMovement()->SetSteeringInput(1.0f);
    //vehicle->GetVehicleMovement()->SetHandbrakeInput(false);

    // set rotaion of vehicle to rotation of the target point
    vehicle->SetActorRotation(target->GetActorRotation());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Vehicle setup in UE4 is tricky. It has a few moving parts that work together. Make sure that you have the initial vehicle setup working otherwise it may not move at all regardless of the code involved. (btw the code looks fine, but I recommend testing in blueprints to verify all is correct with setup)

I made a video about vehicle setup in UE4 on my channel, This might solve your problem. Go through and make sure the setup is the same, since you need to do this whether you are using C++ or blueprints. Here's the link:

[UE4 - How to Make Vehicles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPlVrq8wtSI)